# Having multiple web services run at home on the same ports (80 and 443)

Tags: networking, local, nameserver

Is there a possibility to run several webserver-applications from my home network? So with the same IP forward port 80 and 443 to different devices, depending on the domain name. Right now I use different ports, like 1001, 1002 and 1003 and on my router forward them to a specific device on the correct ports. What I do want however is to go to sub.mydomaina.nl for application A, sub.mydomainb.nl for application B and so on, or with the same domain, only a different subdomain.

To make things more complicated, I'm running two networks at home. I have the 192.168.2.x-network from which I run a router as a private network at the 192.168.1.x-range. On both networks I have web applications running. At the moment it's just two, Synology and Pihole but I want to experiment with converting an old laptop to an Apache-server and be able to run websites from there. I know that I can configure multiple domains in Apache but could that also work for other devices? How would I configure this?

Is this possible, and if it is possible how would I achieve this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that I can configure multiple domains in Apache but could that also work for other devices? How would I configure this?

Yes, if you configure Apache as a *reverse proxy* it can forward the requests to other webservers based on domain (or even based on URL path). Then it's enough to forward ports 80 & 443 to the central Apache server and it'll route to individual apps.

You need to load the [`proxy` and `proxy_http`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) modules in Apache, and the most basic configuration would look like this (for one domain):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.example.com
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.2.x
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see it works very much like a regular Apache vhost, only instead of DocumentRoot or Alias you specify a remote URL via ProxyPass. (There are actually 3–4 different ways of doing the same thing; you will also find examples with ProxyPass inside a `<Location>` tag, or via SetHandler, or even RewriteRule.)

You may also need the `ProxyPreserveHost` option. If it's enabled the webapp will see it's being accessed through "foo.example.com"; if it's disabled the webapp will see "192.168.2.x" instead. Certain webapps may also require a `ProxyPassReverse` statement in order to rewrite HTTP response headers.

(**Note:** Don't confuse this setup with a *forward* proxy! **Do not** enable the `ProxyRequests` option.)

Finally, HTTPS is also configured in Apache using standard SSLEngine and SSLCertificateFile options – not in the proxied webapp itself. So you can have a single central Certbot installation, just exclude it from proxying using `ProxyPass /.well-known/acme/ !` or similar.

---

This same process also works for Nginx, and in addition there are many products which can't host anything themselves but only work as dedicated proxies (or load balancers). As mentioned in Peleion's post, HAproxy and Træfik are two such examples, although they might just be overkill for your use case.

Comment: Cool! This gives me a lot of options. Going to install Ubuntu on a laptop I had for Windows RDP but I realized I wasn't going to use that so time for a repurpose as an Apache server.

Comment: Okay, I've got it working but now there is one device that's struggling, it's my NAS which operates at port 5000 and 5001. Can I configure a virtualhost in Apache for this ass well? So by going to sub.domain.com it will refer to port 5000 for a non-secured connection and port 5001 when HTTPS is used?

Comment: Yes, you can include port numbers in the ProxyPass URL. But note that HTTPS for [client→Apache] is completely independent from HTTPS for [Apache→NAS]. Or in other words, whether your ProxyPass URL is http:// or https:// doesn't depend on whether it's inside a HTTP or HTTPS vhost.

Comment: So you can, for example, have a `<VirtualHost *:443>` which receives requests via HTTPS, but then forwards them to `ProxyPass / http://mynas.home:5000` in plaintext – or the other way around. (See also the 'SSLProxyEngine' option.)

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is a reverse proxy - it forwards incoming traffic to specific applications according to rules you set. It can be used for anything, not just HTTP/S.

Nginx, Traefik, and HAProxy would all do what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible, but requires a domain name within the
[Domain Name System (DNS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).

You may buy a domain name through a registrar, which handles the
[Domain name registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Domain_name_registration)
and supplies tools to define sub-domains.
An example is [Namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/).

It would be better to buy a static IP address from your ISP, as DNS update propagate
only slowly throughout the world.

Otherwise you would need a
[Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS)
supplier, and to arrange to automatically update you IP whenever it changes.
There are free Dynamic DNS services around, placing some limitations on your
domain name, if you prefer a free server. Paid services place no limits
on the domain-name.

Comment: I already have multiple domain names which I can use for this matter. My IP is not static but it only changes once every year or so but I am going to contact my ISP to get a static ISP.

My question is mostly on how to setup my network to do this and if necessary what equipment would I need to acquire.

Comment: You need no additional equipment - the registrar handles everything. The sub-domains need attention, or they will all translate to the same IP address. Some DNS registrars can handle port-translation for sub-domains. This [link](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9678/2237/how-to-redirect-subdomain-to-a-certain-ip-address-along-with-a-port) might be such an example, so verify this with your registrar(s).