# Add a subdomain redirect in Apache to a Nextcloud instance at a local IP

Tags: apache-http-server, redirection, subdomain, letsencrypt, nextcloud

I have a Raspberry Pi serving a couple of static websites through Apache and doing some other stuff.

Now I've been gifted another Raspberry, so I installed NextCloudPi on it, and I would like to redirect a new subdomain (something like cloud.domain.com) from the first Raspberry to the new. I tried adding on my domain.conf file the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName cloud.domain.com
  RedirectPermanent / <localIP>
</VirtualHost>
```

but that redirects to the default Apache website and breaks my other domains. What is the correct way of redirecting that subdomain?

Also, I would like to use ssl with lets-encrypt for Nextcloud, as I am doing with the main domain: do subdomains require extra certificates? Is a simple Apache redirect enough to ensure secure connections?

**Edit:** using advice from the answers, I'm now trying the following configuration in cloud.conf, but I keep being redirected to one of my other domain sites.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cloud.domain.com
    ServerAlias cloud
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.200
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.200
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /.well-known/acme/ !
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Am I guessing it right that you want the domain to be accessible from the outside, and you already have ports 80/443 forwarded to the first Raspberry Pi?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2):

> do subdomains require extra certificates?

Yes. The certificates list exactly which names they're allowed to represent, and subdomains are not automatically included.

(LE allows you to get a multi-domain certificate, but I wouldn't bother – I think it's cleaner to get a separate one for the new domain, since you're configuring SSLCertificateFile individually for each VirtualHost anyway. Multi-domain certificates are more useful for cases where the same vhost has several ServerAliases, or in case the software just doesn't support TLS SNI at all.)

It *is* actually possible to obtain a "wildcard" certificate for `*.domain.com` from Let's Encrypt, which would cover all possible subdomains, but it's a bit more troublesome in several ways – it will be much easier to let each device take care of its own certificates.

> Is a simple Apache redirect enough to ensure secure connections?

No. Redirects are client-side – they tell the *browser* to directly connect to some other location, and all requests following the redirect will completely bypass the original Apache server. A redirect is functionally no different from just typing the destination URL into your address bar.

> What is the correct way of redirecting that subdomain?

In this situation, you *don't* want a redirect. Instead the requests have to be *relayed* by the original Apache server (as that's the only server accessible from outside, due to limitations of port-forwarding).

This is called **"reverse proxy"** mode (mod_proxy_http), which you enable using **`ProxyPass`** inside your VirtualHost. In many cases, you will also want to enable the `ProxyPreserveHost` option.

See other similar posts, such as: [Having multiple web services run at home on the same ports (80 and 443)](https://superuser.com/questions/1547937/having-multiple-web-services-run-at-home-on-the-same-ports-80-and-443)

Note: With a reverse proxy, your browser is always establishing the TLS connection *only to the proxy* – it does not see the certificate used by the backend server, and indeed it doesn't even know whether the backend connection is HTTPS or just plain HTTP.

This means that Let's Encrypt for 'cloud.domain.com' would need to be set up on the first Raspberry Pi (the proxy). To make your LE client work, you will want to configure Apache to exclude `/.well-known/acme-challenge` from being proxied, using a second ProxyPass with `!` as the destination.

Meanwhile the second Raspberry Pi (the backend) is only accessed by the proxy and is invisible to browsers, so it can use any certificate or even plain HTTP, depending on how comfortable you are with your LAN's internal security.

Note 2: *Do not* enable the 'ProxyRequests' option – that's for "forward proxying" only (like Squid).

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to update my cloud.conf according your answer (it's now in an edit on the question). I'm using ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse, but I'm being redirected to one of my other domains.