# How do I host multiple Web servers behind a single IP address?

Tags: networking, dns, webserver

I have VPS with IP (xx.xx.xx.xxx) with Linux OS. I installed "Gitlab" and running it on port 80, and installed "wiki.js" and running it on port 82, installed "elasticsearch" and running it on port 34000.
I am trying to create 3 A records of my DNS (gitlab.mydomain.com, wiki.mydomain.com, es.mydomain.com) with the IP address. But all are redirecting to gitlab.mydomain.com only.

I can understand it is reading the defualt port 80, so it is getting redirected to gitlab.mydomain.com

So i tried to update the A record "points to" with port number in the end (xx.xx.xx.xxx:82), but it doesnt accept and asked to enter a valid IP address, so I have to forcefully give same IP address to all 3 A records.

how can i make the DNS understand to point to different ports on the same IP. I am pretty new to this hosting, if I should not use A record what is that I have to use ? Any help appericiated.

Let me know I am not clear.

Comment: This has been answered in several older threads; it cannot be done using purely just DNS – search for "reverse proxy" and "ProxyPass".

Comment: user1686 is correct, what you're asking for cannot be done using DNS. If you don't provide a port, a web browser will go to port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS. You can use nginx to sit in front of all your sites with all their ports. Here are the instructions: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/. And here is a full configuration: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you can't do this purely through DNS.

DNS *technically* supports this, there are two DNS record types which allow specifying a service location (host:port) for a given domain name – but neither of them will help in yoru situation.

- The older 'SRV' record type is commonly used for other applications, but it is **not** recognized by any web browser or HTTP client.
- The newer 'HTTPSSVC' record type is still in draft and will be supported only by very new browsers. And as its name implies, it *only* works for HTTPS – not basic plaintext HTTP.

You will need an HTTP-level solution – a *reverse proxy* which accepts all requests on port 80 (or 443), then forwards them based on the received "virtual host" name to the correct internal server.

Standard webservers (Apache httpd, Nginx) can be used as reverse proxies. There are also dedicated programs (HAproxy, Traefik). All of them will handle HTTPS as well.

See also:

- [Having multiple web services run at home on the same ports (80 and 443)](https://superuser.com/questions/1547937/having-multiple-web-services-run-at-home-on-the-same-ports-80-and-443/)

Comment: Reverse proxy is not necessarily needed. You can configure Apache or other webserver so that when it sees it has been accessed with the hostname of "wiki.mydomain.com" it will just redirect the browser to port 82, and if it has been accessed with the hostname of "es.mydomain.com" it will redirect to port 34000. It is pretty easy to configure.