# Same ports with different domains(subdomains) with different services(websites) on same server

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, port-forwarding, ssl, ports

Here is my setup:

-RasPI static ip with 192.168.x.x resolving to my domain blah.xyz and port 443 open on my router forwarding to my Pi

-Vaultwarden(bitwarden) running within a docker container using https port (443)

-Nextcloud cloud storage using apache running over 4433 (ssl)

-Have a domain blah.xyz with two subdomains: a.blah.xyz, b.blah.xyz

What I want to do:
Have vaultwarden and nextcloud running under the same port (443) but have vaultwarden resolve to a.blah.xyz and have my nextcloud (website) resolving to b.blah.xyz.

Now, I am aware of a virtual hosts file using apache or nginx as a way to make this happen, but using vaultwarden within a docker is throwing me off and not sure where to go from there. I know i could just buy another domain, but I would rather not do that.

Any ideas? If this makes sense of course.

Edit:

I have set this up successfully now.

Comment: Does this answer the question? https://superuser.com/a/1547984/1686

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using Vaultwarden within Docker is throwing me off and I am not sure where to go from there.

Assuming your [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) (e.g. Apache/Nginx), Nextcloud and Vaultwarden are all on the same server (i.e. your Raspberry Pi), neither Nextcloud nor Vaultwarden (outside its container) can operate on port 443, since that port will be in use by your reverse proxy itself.

In the case of Vaultwarden, [according to the official GitHub page](https://github.com/dani-garcia/vaultwarden), the example command to invoke Vaultwarden is:

`docker run -d --name vaultwarden -v /vw-data/:/data/ -p 80:80 vaultwarden/server:latest`

In that example, according to [this official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/), the `-p` command maps the host and container ports (`host:container`) which allow access to the container. So it is likely possible to change `-p 80:80` to something like  `-p 4444:80` to set the Vaultwarden access port to e.g. 4444 on your host (e.g. Raspberry Pi).

---

*Please note that there may be other considerations (e.g. additional options/steps required, etc.) associated with changing ports or reverse proxying for Vaultwarden/Bitwarden under Docker. One thing that I saw mentioned a couple of times in different contexts was ROCKET_PORT settings. Another consideration seems to be web sockets (primarily related to configuring your reverse proxy).*

---

It's probably worth noting that [Vaultwarden has reverse proxy examples](https://github.com/dani-garcia/vaultwarden/wiki/Proxy-examples) (including for Apache and Nginx) available on its GitHub page.

> [I want to have] Vaultwarden and Nextcloud running under the same port (443) but have Vaultwarden resolve to `a.blah.xyz` and have my Nextcloud (website) resolving to `b.blah.xyz.`

Then you'll likely need two virtual hosts (Apache) or two server blocks (Nginx) which both respond to port 443 and proxy traffic based on the domain. One entry will proxy requests to Nextcloud on e.g. port 4433 and the other to Vaultwarden on e.g. port 4444.

Comment: Thanks, this helped to clear up the issue. I successfully used two virtual hosts within apache with the reverse proxy accepting all 443 incoming requests then sending it on its way to the two other ports that nextcloud and docker(vaultwarden) are using based on the subdomain

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear you got things working. =)